# ArcGIS Arcade code not giving desired outcome

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade, if-else

I have the following code below. I'm trying to search for a text inside a string from a date field and populate it with the associated month with ArcGIS Arcade. So far I just keep getting the default return statement of 'none'. Any thoughts? Does it have something to do with the Find function?

```
var date  = Text($feature.DATE);
if (Find('2023/01/01', date, 0) > -1) {
   return 'January';
} else {
   return 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The string returned from the Text function is in the format "2023-10-16T10:02:49.456-04:00"

You have to change your if statement to this. Note that you shouldn't use [reserved words](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/reserved/) (such as Date) for variable names.

```
var theDate  = Text($feature.DATE);
if (Find('2023-01-01', theDate, 0) > -1) {
  return 'January';
} else {
  return 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked.

```
 var theDate  = Text(ToUTC($feature.DATE), 'M/D/Y');
    Var left = Left(theDate, 2);
    if (left == '1/') {
       return 'January';
    } else if (left == '2/') {
       return 'February';
    } else if (left == '3/') {
       return 'March';
    } else if (left == '4/') {
       return 'April';
    } else if (left == '5/') {
       return 'May';
    } else if (left == '6/') {
       return 'June';
    } else if (left == '7/') {
       return 'July';
    } else if (left == '8/') {
       return 'August';
    } else  (left == '9/') {
       return 'September';
    }
```

Comment: You can simply use `Text(ToUTC($feature.DATE), 'MMMM')` to return the month

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by Kenbuja, minus the timezone transformation.

```
Text($feature.DATE, 'MMMM')
```

See https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#text for other format string options.